# Can I make sure that a certain thread always works last, without semaphores?

Tags: c, multithreading, posix, mutex

So I have two threads. One does math, the other displays the result of the math. Sometimes, the result thread goes first and displays a 0 instead of a valid result. How can I prevent this?

```
void *math  (void *arg);
void *result(void *arg);

int a;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    pthread_t mathT;
    pthread_t resultT;

    pthread_create(&mathT, NULL, math, NULL);
    pthread_create(&resultT, NULL, result, NULL);

    pthread_join(mathT, NULL);
    pthread_join(resultT, NULL);

    return 0;
}

void *math(void *arg) {
    a = 9 + 9;
    return NULL;
}

void *result(void *arg) {
    printf("%d", a);
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: What's the point of having two threads then?  Just have one thread which invokes the two functions serially.

Comment: That's not the point. Of course I can do this serially, but no, I have to use separate threads.

Comment: Put the `pthread_join(mathT)` ahead of the `pthread_create(resultT)`.

Comment: try to create result thread in the `math(void*)` ? it may make sures the result thread is following the math thread.

Answer (score 0):

pthread_cond_wait() block the current thread and then use pthread_cond_signal() or pthread_cond_broadcast() to awake it